# Fresh data vs. locally cached data in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Okay, so I have a LINQ to SQL system set up on a WCF service. My application contains a reference to this service which it uses to collect data from an SQL database. I use a DataContext object which was generated by SQLMetal.exe.

I have two entity collections in my DataContext object, Clients and Groups. Each Client contains a field which says how many Groups it belongs to (a comma separated list of Group IDs).

In the application, I have a table of Clients. If I select one and click a button, a second table shows details of the Groups that Client is a part of.

Here's the question: When I click this button, do I go to the database for the Groups each time, or should I load the Groups when the application starts and sift through those? The latter would be quicker, but I want a concurrent solution.

The second question (I know there shouldn't be two really, but I just realised I might be confused on this issue): when I run a LINQ query on a collection in my DataContext object, am I getting the latest database data?

Thanks.

Comment: I could reply to the three answers or I could just reply once. Three great answers with exactly the sort of information I was looking for. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your second question - Yes, each query against LINQ to SQL results in a SQL statement issued to the backing database. And to clarify further this is each time to attempt to enumerate a LINQ statement. I don't mean to imply that every LINQ statement is sent to the database immediately, which of course it isn't.

The first part on caching vs. querying each time is dependent upon other factors. Is it necessary? Meaning, is there a performance hit you're trying to correct? Also how "stale" can the data afford to be before it becomes a concern to your users? Those are question you'd need to take back to the application owners to decide.

Answer (score 1):

As with most real world performance questions... it depends. The best way to tell is to write your application with what 'feels right' and then if performance is a concern, measure and change accordingly.

Yes, you'll be getting the latest database information.

Answer (score 1):

Unless loading the groups takes a significant amount of time, don't cache.
Premature optimisation is never a good idea.
Just bear in mind that you might want to and make sure your collection of groups is nicely decoupled, optimising if you have to will be relatively simple.